# Объясните пожалуйста в чем роль данной функции? Она выступает в роли обертки? Для чего она нужна?

Tags: javascript

```
(function(){
...(много других функций)
})();
```

Comment: Это способ исполнить код, не оставляя мусор в глобальном пространстве имён. Инкапсуляция. [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Comment: кроме инкапсуляции, есть еще например такие места, где нет возможности вызвать существующую функцию именно так как хочется\требуется по тз(кол-во и расположение аргументов передаваемых в функцию жестко ограничено). например колбэки в том же **ForEach** `[1, 2, 3].forEach(callback, thisArg)` тут в колбэк отправится 3 аргумента - елемент массива, его индекс и исходный массив. без прослойки нет возможности ни добавить пару дополнительных аргументов, ни даже поменять местами имеющиеся. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самовызывающаяся функция.

Функция образует область видимости, поэтому объявленные в ней переменные не видны снаружи.